# How to speed up multiple calls of NonlinearModelFit?

Tags: performance-tuning, fitting, compile

I'm trying to do an insane amount of non-linear fits to large amounts of data sets. However, I found that the `NonlinearModelFit` is horribly slow.

Here's the setup:

The dataset looks like so:

```
out={  
{
 {1, R1, val, err},
 {2, R1, val, err},
 {3, R1, val, err}
},  
{
 {2, R2, val, err},
 {3, R2, val, err},
 {5, R2, val, err}
},  
...}
```

, hence each element of the total data list is a list of same `r` values in ascending order (`Rn < R(n+1)`), with different indizes(these can have values 0,1,2,4,5,8) and different function values and errors.

I'm fitting the datasets as follows:

```
TableMV1combined={}; EstVarMV1combined={}; M0 = 4;  
Do[If[Length[tab[[2]]] > 0,  
 jck = tab[[1]];  
 FitV1combined[beg_, end_] := FitF3combined[beg, end, tab[[2]]];  
 FitTableV1combined =
  FitF3Tablecombined[FitV1combined, tab[[2]]];  
 input = DeleteCases[FitTableV1combined, {___, Missing[], ___}];  
 For[i = 1, i <= Length[input], i++,  
  {AppendTo[
   TableMV1combined, {input[[i]][[1]], input[[i]][[4]], 
   input[[i]][[5]], input[[i]][[12]], input[[i]][[19]][[7]]}];  
   AppendTo[
   EstVarMV1combined, {input[[i]][[1]], input[[i]][[4]], 
   input[[i]][[5]], input[[i]][[20]]}];}];  
 ClearAll[jck, input];];, {tab, {  
{0, out0}, {1, out1}, {2, out2}, {3, out3}, {4, out4},  
{5, out5}, {6, out6}, {7, out7}, {8, out8}, {9, out9},  
{10, out10}, {11, out11}, {12, out12}, {13, out13},  
{14, out14}, {15, out15}, {16, out16}, {17, out17},  
{18, out18}, {19, out19}, {20, out20}, {21, out21},  
{22, out22}, {23, out23}, {24, out24}, {25, out25},  
{26, out26}, {27, out27}, {28, out28}, {29, out29},  
{30, out30}  
}}];  
ClearAll[M0];
```

Here I'm using the following `ParallelTable` function to utilize parallelization:

```
FitF3Tablecombined[FitF3combined_, formatedDataTrimmed_] :=  
Flatten[ParallelTable[{jck, beg, end,  
formatedDataTrimmed[[beg + 1]][[1]][[2]],  
formatedDataTrimmed[[Length[formatedDataTrimmed] - end]][[1]][[2]],  
A0 /. FitF3combined[beg, end]["BestFitParameters"],  
A1 /. FitF3combined[beg, end]["BestFitParameters"],  
A2 /. FitF3combined[beg, end]["BestFitParameters"],  
A3 /. FitF3combined[beg, end]["BestFitParameters"],  
A5 /. FitF3combined[beg, end]["BestFitParameters"],  
A8 /. FitF3combined[beg, end]["BestFitParameters"],  
M /. FitF3combined[beg, end]["BestFitParameters"],  
c0 /. FitF3combined[beg, end]["BestFitParameters"],  
c1 /. FitF3combined[beg, end]["BestFitParameters"],  
c2 /. FitF3combined[beg, end]["BestFitParameters"],  
c3 /. FitF3combined[beg, end]["BestFitParameters"],  
c5 /. FitF3combined[beg, end]["BestFitParameters"],  
c8 /. FitF3combined[beg, end]["BestFitParameters"],  
FitF3combined[beg, end]["ParameterErrors"],  
FitF3combined[beg, end]["EstimatedVariance"]},  
{beg, 1, Length[formatedDataTrimmed] - 8, 1},  
{end, 0,(*Length[formatedDataTrimmed]-beg-4*)4, 2}], 1];
```

The actual non-linear model is:

```
FitF3combined[beg_, end_, formatedDataTrimmed_] := 
NonlinearModelFit[{#1, #2, #3} & @@@ 
Flatten[Table[formatedDataTrimmed[[i]], 
{i, beg + 1, Length[formatedDataTrimmed] - end}], 1],  
{F3[A0, M, R, c0]*KroneckerDelta[sme, 0] +  
F3[A1, M, R, c1]*KroneckerDelta[sme, 1]*UnitStep[R - (sme/Nτ)] +  
F3[A2, M, R, c2]*KroneckerDelta[sme, 2]*UnitStep[R - (sme/Nτ)] +  
F3[A3, M, R, c3]*KroneckerDelta[sme, 3]*UnitStep[R - (sme/Nτ)] +  
F3[A5, M, R, c5]*KroneckerDelta[sme, 5]*UnitStep[R - (sme/Nτ)] +  
F3[A8, M, R, c8]*KroneckerDelta[sme, 8]*UnitStep[R - (sme/Nτ)],  
M > 0 && M < 15},  
{A0, A1, A2, A3, A5, A8, {M, M0}, {c0, 0}, {c1, 0}, 
{c2, 0}, {c3, 0}, {c5, 0}, {c8, 0}}, {sme, R},  
Weights -> 
1 / #4^2 & @@@ Flatten[Table[formatedDataTrimmed[[i]], 
{i, beg + 1, Length[formatedDataTrimmed] - end}], 1]];
```

And finally the actual fit function:

```
F3[A_, M_, R_, c_] := A*Exp[-M*R]/R + c;
```

The parameter `Nτ` is known at runtime.

To wrap it up: I'm trying to fit the amplitudes `Ai`, asymptotic constants `ci`, and the common exponent `M` while varying the maximum and minimum values of `R`. For each `R` value I eventually have different data points separated via the index `sme`. That index in combination with the external parameter `Nτ` and the `UnitStep` function determines if the individual data point should contribute.
However, I find that the fit of one set of data points (one ensemble `out` which results in ~100 possible fit-sets (aka distinct combinations of the minimal and maximal value of `R`)) takes between 10 and 20 minutes. Thus the fit of all 31 sets takes several hours which is unacceptable.

Any hints on how I could improve the procedure? Would it be sensible to eventually compile the linear combination of `F3`-calls?

**EDIT:** As requested by Henrik, here's an example of a dataset

```
out0={{{1, 0.414225, 1.40345, 0.17096}, {2, 0.414225, 1.65493, 
 0.0215624}, {3, 0.414225, 1.85901, 0.0129845}}, {{2, 0.434475, 
 1.43753, 0.0484699}, {3, 0.434475, 1.63697, 0.0259172}}, {{1, 
 0.450238, 1.09145, 0.0738484}, {2, 0.450238, 1.24257, 
 0.0243813}, {3, 0.450238, 1.41758, 0.0153114}}, {{2, 0.467925, 
 1.05682, 0.0439015}, {3, 0.467925, 1.22577, 0.0272181}}, {{2, 
 0.498813, 0.730337, 0.0536427}, {3, 0.498813, 0.87497, 
 0.0313678}}, {{1, 0.514863, 0.495473, 0.150721}, {2, 0.514863, 
 0.621701, 0.0420051}, {3, 0.514863, 0.754838, 0.0281385}}, {{2, 
 0.52975, 0.587331, 0.0466759}, {3, 0.52975, 0.665299, 
 0.0319068}}, {{2, 0.544813, 0.526371, 0.0926066}, {3, 0.544813, 
 0.591536, 0.0552175}}, {{2, 0.5583, 0.418403, 0.0475843}, {3, 
 0.5583, 0.484318, 0.0334907}}, {{2, 0.572325, 0.371991, 
 0.0623067}, {3, 0.572325, 0.410476, 0.0457513}}, {{3, 0.586425, 
 0.32778, 0.136238}}, {{2, 0.612038, 0.207978, 0.0797852}, {3, 
 0.612038, 0.239743, 0.0636066}}, {{2, 0.624175, 0.248989, 
 0.05412}, {3, 0.624175, 0.241667, 0.039516}}, {{1, 0.637375, 
 0.250798, 0.087002}, {2, 0.637375, 0.204584, 0.0455255}, {3, 
 0.637375, 0.201414, 0.0371171}, {5, 0.637375, 0.289974, 
 0.0277755}}, {{2, 0.649525, 0.0612087, 0.0821179}, {3, 0.649525, 
 0.108233, 0.0470898}, {5, 0.649525, 0.223332, 0.0323102}}, {{1, 
 0.67315, -0.00623123, 0.151202}, {2, 0.67315, 0.0699974, 
 0.0552972}, {3, 0.67315, 0.106196, 0.0450462}, {5, 0.67315, 
 0.18297, 0.0345499}}, {{2, 0.68465, 0.0617554, 0.0744936}, {3, 
 0.68465, 0.0679903, 0.0510932}, {5, 0.68465, 0.138326, 
 0.0381582}}, {{3, 0.707113, 0.136617, 0.0786026}, {5, 0.707113, 
 0.152304, 0.0450428}}, {{2, 0.718075, 0.116889, 0.0638092}, {3, 
 0.718075, 0.0857912, 0.0509252}, {5, 0.718075, 0.110423, 
 0.0418042}}, {{2, 0.728875, 0.0119743, 0.0857345}, {3, 0.728875, 
 0.0373805, 0.058675}, {5, 0.728875, 0.0884664, 0.0413072}}, {{2, 
 0.739513, 0.072656, 0.0726864}, {3, 0.739513, 0.0543086, 
 0.0511731}, {5, 0.739513, 0.0810656, 0.0409819}}, {{2, 0.75, 
 0.0468357, 0.071699}, {3, 0.75, 0.044545, 0.0515765}, {5, 0.75, 
 0.0735967, 0.0356424}}, {{3, 0.76035, -0.00634004, 0.0592361}, {5, 
 0.76035, 0.0437272, 0.0396548}}, {{3, 0.77055, -0.0118407, 
 0.0426499}, {5, 0.77055, 0.0343026, 0.0385705}}, {{3, 
 0.790575, -0.0101993, 0.0533663}, {5, 0.790575, 0.0283652, 
 0.0383988}}, {{3, 0.800388, -0.0048569, 0.0483566}, {5, 0.800388, 
 0.0242973, 0.0424175}}, {{3, 0.810088, 0.0801341, 0.0630511}, {5, 
 0.810088, 0.0668193, 0.0510046}}, {{5, 0.819675, 0.00868241, 
 0.10596}}, {{3, 0.82915, -0.0293577, 0.0721665}, {5, 
 0.82915, -0.00907686, 0.0473577}}, {{3, 0.838525, 0.0299376, 
 0.0488719}, {5, 0.838525, 0.0330556, 0.0440675}}, {{3, 
 0.847788, -0.0164008, 0.0556874}, {5, 0.847788, 0.00581662, 
 0.043372}}};
```

I'm aware that the fit results from that dataset are rather poor - anyhow that should be irrelevant for the general discussion. Thanks also for the code edit.

**EDIT 2:** I have not tinkered with things like `AccuracyGoal` or `PrecisionGoal` due to my limited knowledge of their impact. However, if that would help already I'd be glad for any advice.

Comment: Please give a minimal example dataset. You have very specialized code and writing an appropriate example dataset would be a pain in the neck.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher I've added an example set for which `Nτ=8` and `jack=0`. Thanks for looking into it.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher and any ideas from your side?

Comment: @gothicVI, when I try copying the code in I get an error that Weights should be a list of real numbers of a pure function.

Comment: @KraZug I never encountered that. Is it possible that the length of the table becomes zero? Could you try again substituting `{beg, 1, Length[formatedDataTrimmed] - 8, 1}` with `{beg, 1, Length[formatedDataTrimmed] - 10, 1}` in the `FitF3Tablecombined` function? That's one change I made in my local code already to gain a bit of speed up.